# How to access name of taxonomy in English for English & Arabic version of website when using wpml plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wpml

How to access name of taxonomy in English for English & Arabic version of website when using WPML plugin

In below code i am assigning taxonomy in div so that i can assign different class to each group/team where team group could be UI designer, Senior Developer, Team Leads etc.

```
<div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-3 row-cols-lg-4 row-cols-xxl-5 <?php echo preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', strtolower($taxonomy->name)); ?>">
```

With above code it add the group/team name as `ui_designer` or `senior_developer` in English version however it add group/team name in Arabic for Arabic version which is obvious. How can i assign class name in English for Arabic version also

I am not a WP developer i am trying to change this code so that CSS works properly in Arabic version also

Comment: Found https://wpml.org/forums/topic/get-translated-taxonomy-slug-by-default-language-slug/ with a tiny bit of research, and there it refers to https://wpml.org/wpml-hook/wpml_object_id/

Comment: I also looked at wpml.org however didnt find much related to my case as most of article they show changing setting in wpml which i dont want, i am sure there is a way to directly access english or arabic title using code irrespective of which version of website we are on.

Comment: If their support recommends using this, then I am guessing it is probably the quickest way to achieve it.

Comment: Yes, i use paid version my be i contact them as sometime support is very slow to answer.

Comment: Not sure if paid support is supposed to write code for you ... and if not, you will probably get a very similar answer to the one I already linked to. Where is the problem with just using the suggested `wpml_object_id` for this ...?

Comment: I am not looking for code, i just need direction i will figure out a way.. appreciate what you pointed out. I will try the same. since i am not a php code i am just try to solve a problem which actual developer should have done but are not doing it for some reason.. also i have to field i have to get is part of custom post type with some custom field.. so i have to dig a bit to get it right..